# Continuity of $f(xy)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> Let $f(x)$ be defined in neighborhood of $0$ & be continuous at $0$. Prove
>   that $g(x,y) = f(xy)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

The function $h(x,y) = xy$ is continuous at $(0,0)$, so applying the theorem about continuity of composite function, we get that $g$ is also continuous.

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct.